# Fluent Validation CascadeMode.Stop doesnt work on childrules

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

Validator class like below and it is FluentValidation 9.3.0. I want to return first failure message from this code block but every time it returns all failure messages. I didnt see any example in documents. Is there any way ?

Global setting should be `CascadeMode.Continue` only this code block should be `CascadeMode.Stop`.

```
RuleFor(f => f).Cascade(CascadeMode.Stop)
            .ChildRules(
            f =>
            {
                RuleFor(f => f.DefaultName.Primary)
                  .Must(f => !char.IsDigit(f.First()))
                  .WithMessage("IsDigit1");;
                RuleFor(f => f.DefaultName.Secondary)
                 .Must(f => !char.IsDigit(f.First()))
                 .WithMessage("IsDigit2");;
                RuleFor(f => f.DefaultName.Primary)
                 .MinimumLength(10)
                 .WithMessage("MinimumLength1");
                RuleFor(f => f.DefaultName.Secondary)
                 .MinimumLength(10)
                 .WithMessage("MinimumLength2");
            });
```

Comment: Which version of FluentValidation are you using?

Comment: @JonasWeinhardt FluentValidation.AspNetCore(9.3.0)

Answer (score 0):

The `CascadeMode` **property** is only set for validators within the same rule chain.
So in order for your validators to work you need to define the `CascadeMode` in each `RuleFor()`

```
RuleFor(f => f).ChildRules(
  f => {
    RuleFor(f => f.DefaultName.Primary)
      .Cascade(CascadeMode.Stop)
      .Must(f => !char.IsDigit(f.First()))
      .WithMessage("IsDigit1");;
    RuleFor(f => f.DefaultName.Secondary)
      .Cascade(CascadeMode.Stop)
      .Must(f => !char.IsDigit(f.First()))
      .WithMessage("IsDigit2");;
    RuleFor(f => f.DefaultName.Primary)
      .Cascade(CascadeMode.Stop)
      .MinimumLength(10)
      .WithMessage("MinimumLength1");
    RuleFor(f => f.DefaultName.Secondary)
      .Cascade(CascadeMode.Stop)
      .MinimumLength(10)
      .WithMessage("MinimumLength2");
  });
```

[DotNet Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/a1oVlI)

**FluentValidation 11 and newer+**

To avoid repetition, you set the `AbstractValidator.RuleLevelCascadeMode` property in your validators constructor. [docs](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/cascade.html)

```
public class MyClassValidator: AbstractValidator <MyClass> {
  public MyClassValidator() {
    RuleLevelCascadeMode = CascadeMode.Stop;
    RuleFor(f => f).ChildRules(
      f => {
        RuleFor(f => f.DefaultName.Primary)
          .Must(f => !char.IsDigit(f.First()))
          .WithMessage("IsDigit1");;
        RuleFor(f => f.DefaultName.Secondary)
          .Must(f => !char.IsDigit(f.First()))
          .WithMessage("IsDigit2");;
        RuleFor(f => f.DefaultName.Primary)
          .MinimumLength(10)
          .WithMessage("MinimumLength1");
        RuleFor(f => f.DefaultName.Secondary)
          .MinimumLength(10)
          .WithMessage("MinimumLength2");
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: RuleLevelCascadeMode for v 11, i had 9. And DefaultName is localize string variable, so primary and secondary are same value but different language. Rules should work for them same time and it should return first failure message. I didnt find any way . i rewrite it with DependentRules

Comment: You're right about the `RuleLevelCascadeMode` for v11+, I missed that.  However, the rest of your use-case, you should include that in the question?